# How do I correctly run regression-adjustment on a ratio metric?

Tags: math, statistics, experimental-design

I have some experiment data where I have been using the CUPED methodology outlined in a [microsoft paper](https://www.exp-platform.com/Documents/2013-02-CUPED-ImprovingSensitivityOfControlledExperiments.pdf) to adjust the post-assignment data using the pre-assignment data.

One of my metrics is a composite metric where I have, for each user, the total purchase value in the experiment and the total purchase count in the experiment. I'm using the totals to calculate a population mean for the resulting metric (i.e. group means are SUM(numerator)/SUM(denominator).

I want to adjust this based on pre-experiment data, but I know that I have to adjust for the covariance between the numerator and denominator when I do the adjustment. Conveniently there's no case where there's a 0 denominator for a non-zero numerator.

For other metrics, I was using this approach:

```
theta = covariance(metric, covariate) / variance(covariate)
adjusted_metric = metric - (covariate - covariate_mean) x theta
```

I can calculate the covariance matrix between pre/post and num/denom easily enough, but it's unclear to me how I can use that to do a linear adjustment on the numerator/denominator, and if this is valid.

I tried doing a basic regression here, but the results I got seemed off.